# Opening/Reading CSV file from Cloud Storage to Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, dialogflow-es

Is there a way to read and print the data in Cloud Functions from a csv file in Google Cloud Storage?

The Cloud Function API document only says things about downloading the object to your local machine.

I'm creating a fulfillment on dialogflow that will open and read some CSV file on Cloud storage via Cloud functions depending on the query of the user.

Answer (score 3):

Broadly speaking, you can "download" your cloud storage object to either a NodeJS stream or string, and then parse the CSV from that stream or string. Using a stream is more complicated, but best if your CSV is very large. If your CSV is small and can fit in memory, a string is easier.

To get the data, you can use the [Cloud Storage node.js library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs). In particular, you can use the [`createReadStream()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#createReadStream) method or the [`download()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#download) method of the File object to get a stream or a string, respectively.

Once you have that, you can use the [CSV Parse API](https://csv.js.org/parse/api/) library for node.js.

Comment: Do you have to use any awaits to wait on the file stream to complete?

Comment: `createReadStream()` is event based and does not use async/await. `download()` returns a Promise, so you can use await on it. If you have further specific questions, you may want to open up a new question with details and examples of the code that is causing you problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java then you can use `google-cloud-java`'s native Java API (NIO) to access files from Google Cloud Storage. See [this page](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-contrib/google-cloud-nio) for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getFileData() {
    const bucketName = 'bucket-name';
    const filePath = 'prefix/file-name.csv';
    const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filePath);

    const csvData = await file.download().then(function(contents) {
        console.log("ASCII Contents", contents);
        return contents.toString('ascii');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error File Path:", filePath);
    });
    console.error("CSV File Content:", csvData);
}

getFileData().catch(console.error);
```